# Navigating between two view controller of the same class?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my project, I am having a navigation controller.In one of the view controller class I am having two views.One is actually created when I added the class and another is added manually by myself.So both the views having same class.

My problem is when I want to navigate from one of those views to another.Its navigation fine for me.But when I come back and again go to the view, app getting crash with error message "'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported ()'
"

Please remember I am tring to navigate between the views of same class.

Navigating code is,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
```

What would be my problem?

Please share your ideas.

This is the code I used

```
- ( IBAction ) askForPaymentType:(id)sender {

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewPaypal animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController viewControllers]);

}
```

Comment: Before pushing print your  [self.navigationController viewControllers]; if your view controller is present in that array then first remove it from navigation controllers stack. other trick u can try is make another object and try to push it.

Comment: I checked, it contains two objects.Those are the objects I navigated to reach this view.In those which object I should remove?

Comment: the two objects, do they have the same address in memory ??

Comment: No all contains different addresses

Comment: You are confusing between view controller and view.  A view controller can be used to manage more than one view. Perhaps if you post some code then we can see better how you did it.

Comment: Post some code as you are talking to navigate between views not viewControllers. So post some code.

Comment: Your problem is not that they are objects of the same class, it's that they are the same instance/object!

Comment: You should add the actual log output to the your question. Move the log before the actual push and show the log for the first and second attempt. Also pls show how you go back to the initial view controller.

Comment: whats strategy you are using to come back?

Comment: Used "[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];" to come back.

Comment: You need to provide more context. In what controller is the above code? How did you get to this point in the controller hierarchy. What are the 2 controllers you see when you log self.navigationController.viewControllers?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the addSubview method. Take another view in xib of same class and add the view on main view. After you finished just `removeFromSuperview` and clear its memory.

```
- ( IBAction ) askForPaymentType:(id)sender {
[self.view addSubview:viewPaypal];
}
```